# .container not covering full height

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Best to explain with the screenshots, this is my application layout (rails):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzPgy.png

And here is the issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtgNG.jpg

The colored bg just below the header is the .main class, which I want to be covering the entirety of the site from the header down. I'm not really sure why it gets pushed to a fixed height there. CSS:

```
/* Global Styles */
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

/* Structure styles (footer css) */
.container, .main {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  background-color: #f4f4ec;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: In doing the jsfiddle, It worked fine. So I looked back into the css and tried to see what other styling might be affecting it. Apparently it was the footer styling, (specifically, the height). I don't know why this also affected .main but now I can look into it. Thanks for leading me to the answer!